# table of contents with progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar, tableofcontents

I'm trying to make a table of contents with a progress bar that evolves according to the progress of the reading of my article. 
My article contains several titles (title1, title2, ...). Each title in my menu has a progress bar. 
How can I make the progress bar evolve according to the reading progress?

Here is my HTML / CSS / JS code minify:
https://jsfiddle.net/Bernardooooo/c71ybgx5/2/

```
$self = this;

this.$content = $('.page__body');
this.$sidebar = $('.page__sidebar');
this.$title = $('.page__title', this.$content);
this.$header = $('.header');
this.offset = this.$header.outerHeight();
this.arrayTitle = [];

$self.$title.each(function(id) {
  // Calc here
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  let scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    // update % width progress bar 
  element.progress.css('width', percent + '%');
});
```

I get the "header" because this one is fixed so I need to know its height.
I'm already picking up a few things, but I don't know how to do the math. 
Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 2):

Ive written some jsfiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/4twgse1j/

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {

     let scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
     let placement1,placement2,placement3,placement4

     placement1 = $('#title1-body').height()
     placement2 = placement1 + $('#title2-body').height()
     placement3 = placement2 + $('#title3-body').height()
     placement4 = placement4 + $('#title4-body').height()

    if(scroll<placement1){
      $('.title1-prog div').width( ((scroll/placement1)*100)+'%')
    }

    if(scroll>placement1 && scroll<placement2){
      $('.title2-prog div').width(((scroll-placement1)/(placement2-placement1)*100)+'%')
    }      
  });
```

Ive just done section 1 and 2, and hopefully you can get the pattern and you can do 3 and 4 yourself